# Multiple read() operations on the same file

Tags: c, file-io, unistd.h

I'm looking at using the read() function to read in entire data structures, each of which will be of the same type as any other, but with different data, then place them into a linked list. For some reason I can't seem to find any specific information on how to terminate a loop which would include `read(fp, &tmp, sizeof(struct foo))` followed by `new_node(tmp)`.

I would like to be able to simply read until EOF, but I'm not aware of how to go about determining with the read() function where EOF is. Obviously, I could use a workaround with the write() function where I would include the number of structures in the file before writing, and then terminate the read function when I reach that number, but that seems a bit clunky, and avoids the original idea of knowing when the file terminates.

FOLLOW-UP:

I appreciate the assistance, and I've implemented what I've seen. Unfortunately, I believe I may be reading in the wrong information. The pertinent code:

```
struct test_t{
    int data;
    char buf[LEN];
        struct test_t * next;
};

struct test_t * new_node(struct test_t node, struct test_t * tail)
{
    struct test_t * tmp = NULL;

    if(!(tmp = malloc(sizeof(struct test_t))))
        return NULL;

    tmp->data = node.data;
    strcpy(tmp->buf, node.buf);
    tmp->next = NULL;
    if(tail)
        tail->next = tmp;

    return tmp;
}

...

while(read(fd, &tmp, sizeof(struct test_t)) == sizeof(struct test_t)){
    printf("%d, %s\n", tmp.data, tmp.buf);
    tail = new_node(tmp, tail);
    if(head == NULL)
        head = tail;
    printf("%d, %s\n", tail->data, tail->buf);
}

...

fd = open("test.txt", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0666);
iter = head;
while(iter){
    printf("%d\n", write(fd, &iter, sizeof(struct test_t)));
    printf("%d, %s\n", iter->data, iter->buf);
    iter = iter->next;
}
```

This is the output from the write loop:

```
112
1, a
112
2, b
112
3, c
112
4, d
112
5, e
```

The file is saved in binary, but I can make out enough to know that only the tail seems to be written, five times. I'm not sure why that is.

The output for the diagnostic printf's in the read loop is:

```
23728144, 
23728144, 
23728272, 
23728272, 
23728400, 
23728400, 
23728528, 
23728528, 
23728656, 
23728656,
```

The output makes me think it's putting the value of the next pointer into the data int. Any idea why:
1) I might be write()ing the same node five times in a row?
2) I am getting gibberish when I read()?

Comment: Maybe check the return value from `read()` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while (read(fd, &tmp, sizeof(tmp)) == sizeof(tmp))
{
    ...got another one...
}
```

It is conventional to use `FILE *fp;` and `int fd;` (so the name for a file descriptor is `fd` and not `fp`).

The [`read()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/read.html) function returns the number of bytes it read. If there's no more data, it returns 0. For disk files and the like, it will return the requested number of bytes (except at the very end when there might not be that many bytes left to read) or 0 when there's no data left to read (or -1 if there's an error on the device rather than just no more data).  For terminals (and sockets, and pipes), it will read as many bytes as are available rather than wait for the requested size (so each read could return a different size).  The code shown only reads full-size structures and baulks if it gets a short read, EOF or an error.

---

The code by [ensc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2252087/ensc) in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20318828/15168) covers all practical circumstances, but isn't the way I'd write the equivalent loop.  I'd use:

```
struct foo tmp;
ssize_t nbytes;

while ((nbytes = read(fd, &tmp, sizeof(tmp))) != 0)
{
    if ((size_t)nbytes = sizeof(tmp))
        process(&tmp);
    else if (nbytes < 0 && errno == EINTR)
        continue;
    else if (nbytes > 0)
        err_syserr("Short read of %zu bytes when %zu expected on fd %d\n",
                   nbytes, sizeof(tmp), fd);
    else
        err_syserr("Read failure on fd %d\n", fd);
}
```

The two normal cases — a full length record is read OK and EOF is detected — are handled at the top of the loop; the esoteric cases are handled further down the loop. My `err_syserr()` function is `printf()`-like and reports the error given by its arguments, and also the error associated with `errno` if it is non-zero, and then exits.  You can use any equivalent mechanism. I might or might not put the file descriptor number in the error message; it depends on who is going to see the errors. If I knew the file name, I'd certainly include that in the message in preference to the file descriptor.

I don't see any difficulty handling the `nbytes == -1 && errno == EINTR` case, contrary to comments by @ensc.

Answer (score 2):

read returns the number of bytes read. If you perform a read, and the return value is less than the number of bytes you requested, then you know it reached EOF during that read. If it exactly equals the requested number of bytes, then either the file has not reached EOF, or it did, and there are exactly 0 bytes left in the file, in which case the next call to read() will return 0.

```
while(read(fd, &tmp, sizeof(tmp)) > 0) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for (;;) {
    struct foo tmp;
    ssize_t l = read(fd, &tmp, sizeof tmp);

    if (l < 0 && errno == EINTR) {
        continue;
    } else if (l < 0) {
        perror("read()");
        abort();
    } else if (l == 0) {
        break;   /* eof condition */
    } else if ((size_t)(l) != sizeof tmp) {
        abort(); /* something odd happened */
    } else {
        handle(&tmp);
    }
}
```

EDIT:

In my projects I use a generic

```
bool read_all(int fd, void *dst_, size_t len, bool *is_err)
{
        unsigned char *dst = dst_;

        *is_err = false;

        while (len > 0) {
                ssize_t l = read(fd, dst, len);

                if (l > 0) {
                        dst += l;
                        len -= l;
                } else if (l == 0) {
                        com_err("read_all", 0, "read(): EOF");
                        *is_err = (void *)dst != dst_;
                        break;
                } else if (errno == EINTR) {
                        continue;
                } else {
                        com_err("read_all", errno, "read()");
                        *is_err = true;
                        break;
                }
        }

        return len == 0;
}
```

function. <s>Because I prefer the approach to say how much elements are to be read, an `EOF` is handled as an error here.  But it would be trivial to add another `bool *err` argument to the function which is set in the non-EOF error case.</s>  You can use above as

```
while (read_all(fd, &tmp, sizeof tmp, &is_err))
    new_node(&tmp);
```

Comment: When the read() gets the last section of data, won't it return a number between 0 and sizeof(tmp)? Unless of course the file size happens to be a multiple of sizeof(tmp)? Because if so, it's not odd for l != sizeof(tmp).

Comment: @master_latch: whether either `abort()` is appropriate is debatable, but this covers a lot, if not all, of the possible error conditions. Personally, I'd not code it as an infinite loop, either; I'd probably use `while ((l = read(fd, &tmp, sizeof(tmp))) != 0) { ... }`, omitting the EOF detection from the body of the loop because the loop condition detects that.  I'd also put the normal case at the top: `if (l == sizeof(tmp)) { handle(&tmp); } else ... handle errors ...`.

Comment: it would be a bad design when such a layout of the file is allowed.  E.g. the file should contain exactly *n* elements and ends immediately, or you put information into the file how many *n* elements are to be expected and read only so much.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler when putting it in the loop condition it is difficult to deal with the errno = EINTR case (without using the `TEMP_FAILURE_RETRY` GNU macro).  Personally, I do not like assignment-in-loop-conditions either.

Answer (score 2):

Ignoring error conditions, I think this is the basic idea:

```
while (read(fp, &tmp, sizeof(struct foo))==sizeof(struct foo))
    new_node(tmp);
```